# JAX-RS Selected MediaType

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am trying to create a download service with JAX-RS. For this I add a HTTP Header `Content-Disposition` with a filename. In JAX-RS I want to re-use as much as possible and I want to detect the 'selected' response MediaType. e.g.

```
@Path("/download")
public class DownloadResource {
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response download() {
        return Response.ok(new SomeContent())
            // Detect MediaType to decide which file extension has to be used
            .addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"download.?\"")
            .build();
    }
}
```

I want to have a `Content-Disposition` header to offer xml or json as a download (just for this example). But somehow I need to know what the prefered MediaType is of JAX-RS (XML or JSON in this case).

**UPDATE:** After researching further, using the `Filter` would make much more sense. I have updated the code like this:

```
@Path("/download")
public class DownloadResource {
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Attachment
    public Response download() {
        return Response.ok()
                .entity(new SomeContent())
                .build();
    }
}
```

I have added the `@Attachment` annotation here. The definition of it:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Attachment {

}
```

The filter that should add the `Content-Disposition` header.

```
public class AttachmentResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {
            MediaType responseMediaType = responseContext.getMediaType();

            if (responseMediaType instanceof MediaType) {
                String fileExtension = ...; // Has to be build
                responseContext.getHeaders().add("Content-Disposition",
                        "attachment; filename=\"" + "file." + fileExtension + "\""
                );
            }
    }
```

Lastly adding register the filter to the `FeatureContext`.

```
@Provider
public class AttachmentFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
        Attachment attachment = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(Attachment.class);

        if (attachment instanceof Attachment) {
            context.register(AttachmentResponseFilter.class);
        }
    }

}
```

One thing I have to think about is how I can generate a custom filename in `AttachmentResponseFilter`, instead of the fixed "file." string. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide some clarification. What do you mean by *which MediaType has been selected to use*?

Answer (score 0):

I would inject the `HttpServletRequest` via `@Context`.  To determine which format that JAX-RS will select will require you to look at the "Accept" header via `request.getHeader("Accept")`.  Your browser will take just about anything.  But a REST client will often create a header like "Accept: application/json" or something like that.

JAX-RS is going to do this under the covers for you. The JAX-RS request can get you this information to as you point out.

I've got to ask though - why do you care?  One of the points of JAX-RS is to hide this from you - return your object and let something else serialize it for you.